# Error with transition SWIFT 4.2 auto update

Tags: swift, swift4.2

Since I convert to Swift current syntax, two of my pods extension show the same error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'CAEmitterLayerEmitterMode' to type 'CAEmitterLayerRenderMode'
```

at this two line :

```
layer.renderMode = CAEmitterLayerEmitterMode.outline // error
...
layer.renderMode = CAEmitterLayerEmitterMode.surface // error
```

the pods are : `CountdownLabel` and `LTMorphingLabel`

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the framwork as update after create a issue :

[link](https://github.com/lexrus/LTMorphingLabel/pull/115/commits/facd857b77ead0a1c094dfa6634a6e329c6bffff)